# Using Orbit Slider with video

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slider, orbit

I have a question regarding [Orbit Slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider).

I want to place a youtube video in the slider. 
I used **div** and **embed** to replace **img** and was successful. The video can play and stop.

My question is how can I make the slider's timer stop when user presses **PLAY** on the video in the slider?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Orbit slider javascript it works using events. Look for these bits of code in the Orbit JS file

```
  this.$element.bind('orbit.start', function (event, index) {
    self.startClock();
  });

  this.$element.bind('orbit.stop', function (event, index) {
    self.stopClock();
  });
```

These bind the events 'orbit.stop' and 'orbit.start' events to the HTML element (which usually has an ID 'featured' when using the Foundation way of setting up Orbit). So if you trigger these events e.g. 'orbit.stop' from the HTML element it will call the function stopClock(). The following should help...

HTML

```
<a id="stop-button" href="#" class="button rounded">stop</a>
<a id="start-button" href="#" class="button rounded">start</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('#stop-button').on('click',function(){
    $('#featured').trigger('orbit.stop');
});

$('#start-button').on('click',function(){
    $('#featured').trigger('orbit.start');
});


/*using the setup 
<div id="featured">
  <img src="../images/orbit-demo/demo1.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/orbit-demo/demo2.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/orbit-demo/demo3.jpg" />
</div>
*/
```